# SQL world table, need help to show continents with more than 10 countries

Tags: sql, select, sqlhelper

I am trying to learn sql and i have downloaded a world database.
My problem is that i cannot find out how to pick the continents with more than 10 countries in them

My database is:
name: (alle countries in the world)
continent: (Africa, Americas, Asia-Pacific, Europe, Middle East, North America, South America, South Asia)

If someone can push me in the right direction, i would be really glad!

[image]

I know a part of what i need to do, but i am not sure where to put more code to get the result.

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(*)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
```

I got the help i needed, thank you!
The code i'm using is:

```
    SELECT continent, COUNT(*) 
    FROM world
    GROUP BY continent
    HAVING COUNT(name) > 10
```

Comment: Do you know how to count the countries for each continent?

Comment: You would need to update your question to show the table structures, some sample data for those tables, the result you want to achieve based on that data and what you have managed to write on your own

Comment: Just curious, how are Turkey and Russia stored? (Regarding continent.)

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT().

Comment: Your query is fine, you have the continents, you have the count, now add a `HAVING` clause to remove the unwanted continents. (world is not a good name for the table by the way. As it contains countries, it should be called country or countries.)

Comment: Russia and Turkey are both in Europe

Comment: you just have to add `WHERE continent <> 'Antarctica'`, because that's the only continent with less than 10 countries.

Comment: So i need a HAVING but i have been searching all day, where can i find keywords to use? 
I have just followed a guide on the naming patch so i will not us world later on :)

Comment: For MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-H:~:text=HASH-,HAVING,-(R), or in the description of the [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement, which shows all options that can be used in a select.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! 
I got it. 
SELECT continent, COUNT(*) 
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING COUNT(name) >= 10

Comment: "with more than 10 countries" so you should not do `>=10`, but `> 10`  

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the HAVING statement that allows you to filter the results of an aggregation. (As opposed to the WHERE clause, that is executed before the rest of the query).

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(*)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING COUNT(*)>10
```